# How to redirect to admin login page instead of login page for unauthenticated admins in laravel 5.8..15?

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

Does anyone know how to use guards in `redirectTo()` method in Authenticate middleware in laravel 5.8.15(or simply 5.8)?

I get this error

> "Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::redirectTo($request, $guards) should be compatible with Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::redirectTo($request)"

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

protected function redirectTo($request, $guards)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        if (array_first($this->guards) === 'admin') {
            return route('admin.login');
        }
        return route('login');
    }
}

//Updated code but still getting error
//Error:: Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, 
  Closure $next, $guard = NULL) should be compatible with 
  Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, 
  ...$guards)

//Code
....
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
.... 

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.login');
            }
            break;

        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/login');
            }
            break;
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I think it's because there are 2 exactly same named functions existing in the middleware (one in your project, one in Illuminate) which take a different set of parameters.

Comment: Yeah that is the issue as suggested by the error message.. But how can I do that?  Earlier it used to be defined in Exception/handler file

Answer (score 0):

CHeck like this and redirect on your condition

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        switch ($this->getGuard()) {
            case 'admin':
                if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect()->route('admin_login');
                }
                break;
            case 'vendor':
                if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect()->route('vendor_login');
                }
                break;

            case 'user':
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect()->route('user_login');
                }
                break;

            default:
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/login');
                }
                break;
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: use handle not redirect function check the code carefully

Comment: Sir I just updated my question code with updated code and further error. Can you please look into it, maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `render($request, Exception $exception)` in `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` to look like the one below:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if(get_class($exception) != 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException'){
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }


    $guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(),0);
    switch ($guard){
        case 'admin':
            return redirect(route('admin.login'));
            break;
        default:
            return redirect(route('login'));
            break;
    }

}
```